# Metadata Storage for Cassandra/Spark Application

Tags: database, postgresql, cassandra, metadata

We have a growing number of data sets with different quality values, statistics about the datasets and other metadata. What would be the best way to add a metadata management component, storing all the additional information about the datasets? My approach would be the specification of a simple SQL-DB (PostgreSQL). Any suggestions of alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Why not a table in C* to store the metadata?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean C-Store? Why would you recommend it?

Comment: The metadata store should especially fit to our Cassandra stack.

Comment: Could you describe the properties of the datasets that needs to be stored? How is this metadata being used and what is the lifecycle?

Comment: We have timeseries data of signals stored in Cassandra. During the conversion process (and ETL process) I would like to compute statistics about the data sets (e.g.,time ranges, information about the source, occurrences of specific situations, quality values, etc., ). The metadata server just should help to find the perfect data set.

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I would choose the metadata store depending on my query patterns and maintenance requirements. For example if there are lot of datasets and if you are trying to query this metastore to find the perfect dataset for your current usecase, the queries on this metastore will be have filter/select etc, which stikes out Cassandra as metastore from the list. Choosing from Postgres/ MySQL is good, in my opinion. But, this adds a new tool to take care of in your application stack. But if my query patterns/datasets are simple, then choosing Cassandra itself to store the metadata is a choice.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I will store the data in a simple SQL-DB. According to their description, stacks such as Cloudera (Derby?), i.e. systems such as Ambari, Hive or Oozie already have included relational DBMS. I only don't know how easy t would be to use them also for my explicit metadata store.

Comment: You are correct. Typically in prod, the relational system is MySQL. But Postgres also works!